# What's the difference between 部件, 零件, and 配件？

Tags: difference, word

What's the difference between 部件, 零件, and 配件？

I'm trying to translate the English sentence *"Manage parts & accessories retail operations"* and am having difficulty finding the right words for *"parts"* and *"accessories"*.

Also, not sure if I should throw in 辅助品 for *"accessories"* rather than one of the above options.

FYI, this translation is for a vehicle manufacturer.

Answer (score 1):

零件 (parts) and 配件 (accessory) would suffice, in Traditional Chinese.

Answer (score 1):

零件: parts;

配件: accessories;

部件: assembly unit;  部件 is composed of parts 零件;

*parts & accessories* can be 零配件.

So, "*Manage parts & accessories retail operations*" can be interpreted as 管理 零配件 零售运营.